# After Panorama Load SpiderFier stop working

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am plotting markers on map, and for same location I am using this Library [SpiderFy](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier). What I want is to when on each marker clicked the marker Panorama should be display below the map in separate container.

After once Panorama load then SpiderFier stop working and then markers can not Spiderfy again

when Panorama specific code is commented then its start working fine.

What could be the issue ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You haven't provided any code, link, or example to allow us to answer your question.

Comment: I did not post any code here because I want just to know conceptually that when Panorama load on client page then client web browser (my web browser) is continuously syn with Google server ?

Comment: That wasn't the question you asked.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by creating another instance of Google Map like.

```
/*Google Map instance for draw Google Map*/     
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                mapOptions);

/*Google map instance  for StreetView*/
        streeviewMap = new google.maps.Map(document
                .getElementById("images_tab"), mapOptions);
```